# Can I ask user to re-authenticate Apple ID login

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, apple-id

I would like to create a kiosk-mode with limited functionality for my app, which would require a user password to be entered to unlock the kiosk-mode and get back to poweruser-mode.  In doing so, I would prefer to not create my own password system, but I would rather prefer to have the user authenticate using their existing Apple-ID.  They will already be logged into their Apple-ID, but is there a way for me to request they log in again?

Maybe I'm just being lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make users log into their `Apple-ID` again on demand, if needed `Apple` will authenticate users as needed, but for us as app developers this is a closed system.

You can look at `LocalAuthentication` for example like banks do where user would have to authenticate with their passcode or biometric data to access some features of the app...

Comment: Okay thanks, that's what I was suspecting the more I looked into it.